# Found error 'CRASH REPORT Process' on RabbitMQ in every 10 mins

Tags: rabbitmq

[I found error on RabbitMQ in every 10 mins. Please help me to investigate this problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjtyT.png)

Error message.
021-09-09 13:25:30.084 [error] <0.14464.32> CRASH REPORT Process <0.14464.32> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: no function clause matching rabbit_mgmt_wm_node:find_type(rabbit@controller1, []) line 79
2021-09-09 13:25:30.085 [error] <0.14457.32> Ranch listener rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672, connection process <0.14457.32>, stream 1 had its request process <0.14464.32> exit with reason function_clause and stacktrace [{rabbit_mgmt_wm_no

Comment: Which RAbbitMQ version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I use command 'tail -f /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.log' then I found error as below.


[error] <0.14464.32> CRASH REPORT Process <0.14464.32> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: no function clause matching rabbit_mgmt_wm_node:find_type(rabbit@controller1, []) line 79 2021-09-09 13:25:30.085 [error] <0.14457.32> Ranch listener rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672, connection process <0.14457.32>, stream 1 had its request process <0.14464.32> exit with reason function_clause and stacktrace [{rabbit_mgmt_wm_no


It appeared in logs every 10 mins.

Comment: Rabbitmq 3.7.10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Zabbix monitoring the RabbitMQ server every minute which generated a crash-error with the same frequency.

The URL used by Zabbix to monitor contained a domain part to the node name ie. rabbit@my_host.zzz.aws instead of the actual node name as displayed by the console: rabbit@my_host. this explains why rabbit_mgmt_wm_node:find_type failed and crashed.

This was verified using curl as shown below:

```
curl -v -u user:passwd 'http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/nodes/rabbit@my_host?memory=true'
```

which returned a valid response, HTTP/1.1 200 OK, when the node name matched and the crash/error when it did not.

please refer to this thread:
https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/N0EgrLn55XQ

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: If you're interested in this specific question, you can click the “follow” link to receive notifications of new answers. Once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, or create a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) to attract more attention to it. If you have a different but related question then [ask](/questions/ask) it. You can reference this one if it would help provide context.